# Combining Variables

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I have a function:

```
function prodSubSection(div, sec, self) {
   $(".prod-feat").hide();
   $(div + sec).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
   $(self)
     .addClass('prodDetailsOn')
     .parent('li').siblings().find("a")
     .removeClass('prodDetailsOn');
}
```

And here is how I execute it:

```
$("#product1 li.details1 a").click(function() {
   prodSubSection("#product1", ".over", this);
   return false;
});
```

What I would like is to combine `div` and `sec` so above would be:

```
$("#product1 .over").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space:

```
$(div + ' ' + sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a space between `div + sec`... so `div + " " + sec`.

Without the space, you will be looking for `#product1.over`, so an element named `product1` AND has a class of `over`, instead of all elements with a class of `over` INSIDE of an element with the name of `product1`.